# Does adding label to adsense auto ads violate policy?

Tags: ads, adsense

Google auto ads uses a class .google-auto-placed for every auto ad generated. If I add a label to those using a CSS style like the one shown below, does that violate the TOS?

```
 .google-auto-placed::before {
content: "Advertisements";
}
```

Comment: Do you have example of how that looks like? It doesn't affect ad rendering?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a working example. I found this code on a wordpress plugin help page - https://wpadvancedads.com/manual/ad-label-how-to-set-advertisement-label/ (Pls see the final part.) Want to make sure if this is legal before trying.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a violation, I had this implementation for several months & had no issues with Adsense at all.
[Adsense also permit labeling Ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/4533986?hl=en) with **Advertisement** or **Sponsored Links**.